# Problem with Location Manager/Listener on my Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm creating an app which using GPS and Google Maps. I want to draw a line between locations when location is change `(onLocationChanged)`. It works, but blue dot on map (google map) not always is on the same coordinates than i found using `location.getLattitude` and `.getLongtitude` (Line is drawing between last position and new positon).

New position /= Blue dot. Why it's no always the same position? I want to draw line between last blue dot location and new blue dot location. I have permission etc.
(Position go from down to up): https://tinypic.pl/hu8p4zyhhz7f

> onMapReady Function:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        mMap = map;


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            lokalizacja();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkoutActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }


        routeOpts = new PolylineOptions()
                .color(Color.BLUE)
                .width(5 /* TODO: respect density! */)
                .geodesic(true);
        route = mMap.addPolyline(routeOpts);
        route.setVisible(drawTrack);

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this); }
}
```

> localizacja function:

```
public void lokalizacja() {
        //Context context = getApplicationContext();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {




                if (routeOpts != null) {                                               
                        lat = (float) location.getLatitude();
                        lng = (float) location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    List<LatLng> points = route.getPoints();
                    points.add(myLatLng);
                    route.setPoints(points);
                }


            }
```

> onStatusChanged:

```
 @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                Log.d("tocos","StatusChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.d("tocos","Enabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Log.d("tocos","Disabled");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Because Google Maps uses its own set of algorithms to find the position, which may include smoothing algorithms, different location providers, and other adjustments.  I'd be more surprised if it was the same location as just asking GPS.

Comment: Okay, i cant change or disable smoothing algorithms in this blue dot i think. But can i take coordinates of blue dot? Or possibly do you know good smoothing algorithms for gps with implementation?

Comment: map.getMyLocation() returns your location.

Comment: ok i can use it, but how to draw polyline if it's need latitude and longtitude (are diffrent than blue dot with smoothing algorithms)